# python subprocess inside subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script which launch another script 
inside subprocess which launch other subprocesses.

How many level of recursion can we get 
using subrlprocess ?

Is this platform dependant ?

Comment: That is the maximum number of possible processes. On Linux it can be retreived via `cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` and a typical value is 32768, but other limitations like available RAM apply. It might differ on the architecture, the OS and it's settings.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb

Comment: is there any python limitation ?